# Is there any possibility to use Regex in .NET microframework 4.1?

Tags: c#, .net-micro-framework, netduino

I am using netduino and Quectel GSM module and I would like to parse with regex recieved sms. Does anybody knows something about this?

Comment: Micro does have the System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex class.  A contribution made by Julius Friedman and based on Apache's implementation.  Whether your Netduino includes it is hard to tell.  Try it.

Comment: I tried it and I couldn't found it. So I suppose that there is no support for that. Is there any posibility how to add it manually?

Comment: Maybe, dig Framework\Core\System\RegularExpressions\Core_Regex out of the SDK.

Answer (score 3):

Add a Reference to your project -- System.Text.RegularExpressions, then add a using System.Text.RegularExpressions to your source code where you intend to use it.

[image: Adding a reference using Visual Studio]

Comment: If you post a link to the picture a user with more rep can review it and integrate it into your answer. Just use http://imgur.com/ to upload it, that is the service SO uses automaticly when you do have 10 rep.

Comment: Thanks, Scott...that is a better solution than editing my response heavy handedly. I understand part of the edit, however...the two responses that were edited removed useful information, as well as my Happy Coding! signature...not happy about that. Also, the image is already at my site.